# When I am running iplot with pandas dataframe it has given me a big blank output in google colab. How Can I Solve the issue?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, google-colaboratory

```
#importing necessary library for plotly
import plotly as py
import plotly.tools as tls
import cufflinks as cf
py.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from plotly import __version__
import cufflinks as cf
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs,init_notebook_mode,plot,iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
cf.go_offline()
import chart_studio.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
```

#reading the data which is iris dataset

```
df1=pd.read_csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/curran/a08a1080b88344b0c8a7/raw/0e7a9b0a5d22642a06d3d5b9bcbad9890c8ee534/iris.csv")
```

#using iplot to show the interactive plot

```
df1.iplot()
```

#Above code has given big blank output

Comment: A problem might be that you are mixing plotly and matplotlib, two libraries that are very different.  You should choose either one or the other.  (Seaborn is based on matplotlib, so they work together without problem.)

Comment: @JohanC I have tried without  importing them(matplotlib and seaborn) also still the same issue i am facing

Comment: Did you try to remove `%matplotlib inline`? Can you edit your post and change it to a cleaner version?

Comment: @JohanC Yeah. I have edited my post you can check now. I have tried this entire code also but this output has come big blank in google  colab.

Comment: I can draw the following three lines correctly. `import pandas as pd;df1=pd.read_csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/c/iurran/a08a1080b88344b0c8a7/raw/0e7a9b0a5d22642a06d3d5b9bcbad9890c8ee534ris.csv");df1.plot();`

Comment: @r-beginners yeah but i don't want to show the static plot I am trying to use interactive plot using plotly and pandas together